# Set Image source from Callout Menu Flashbuilder?

Tags: android, mobile, flash-builder

I am currently working in Flashbuilder 4.6 to create a mobile tablet application and I have created a menu structure using a callout button with a viewnavigator contained in it.

The issue I am having is that I am trying to set the image source value on one view from this callout menu. The code below is for the firstview in my application, which contains the image I want to change via the menu selection:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Main Page">
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="15" paddingBottom="15" paddingLeft="15" paddingRight="15" gap="5"
                      horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="top"/>
</s:layout>
<s:Image id="Image" width="100%" height="100%" scaleMode="letterbox" smooth="true"
         smoothingQuality="high" source="assets/Image1.png"/>
</s:View>
```

This is the firstview loaded into the application. Then the code below is from one of the menu contained in the callout where i am trying to set the source of the image in the firstview to be equal to a new value, thus changing the main content based on the menu selection:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- components\mobile\views\main_menu.mxml -->
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    title="Menu" initialize="view1_initializeHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.components.SplitViewNavigator;
        import spark.components.ViewNavigator;
        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
        import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;

        import views.CallOutPassBack;
        import views.RightView;

        public var myCallout:CallOutPassBack = new CallOutPassBack();
        public var mainView:RightView = new RightView();

        protected function list_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            trace("at this stage");
            var currentDataItem:Object = event.currentTarget.selectedItem;

            if( currentDataItem.view_id == "dk" ){
                trace(mainView.Image.source.toString());
                mainView.Image.source = "assets/Image_1.5.png";
            }else if( currentDataItem.view_id == "dks" ){
                mainView.Image.source = "assets/Image_2.png";
            }else if( currentDataItem.view_id == "hes" ){
                mainView.Image.source = "assets/Image_3.png";
            }else if( currentDataItem.view_id == "slk" ){
                mainView.Image.source = "assets/Image_4.png";
            }           


        }

        protected function view1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            trace("at this stage2");
        }

        protected function back_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            navigator.popView();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button id="back" label="Back" emphasized="true" click="back_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:actionContent>

<s:List id="list" width="425" height="100%" click="list_clickHandler(event)" labelField="name">
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayCollection>
            <fx:Object name="DK" view_id="dk"/>
            <fx:Object name="DKS" view_id="dks"/>
            <fx:Object name="HES" view_id="hes"/>
            <fx:Object name="SLK" view_id="slk"/>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List></s:View>
```

I have also tried tracing the value to the console for the current source of the image on the first view, however it errors out due to a null value. It wont let me change the image which isreally annoying as I need to change the image on that firstview that is loaded based on the menu item selected in the callout, any ideas?

If someone could tell me how to maybe even change that firstview to a new one via some sort of pushview from the callout I could do it that was I guess but ot ideal.

Thanks

Comment: I have been trying to solve this issue and I cant seem to close the calloutButton thus saving the data from a view within the view navigator. Any ideas?